# RewardBasedVideoAd is couldn't found on scripty

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

Im trying to add RewardBasedVideoAd to my game by watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TwNzVBq2Dtk&t=0s. But, RewardBasedVideoAd cannot found on using GoogleMobileAds.Api; Can u help me pls?

[image]

Comment: I think RewardBasedVideoAd api is changed to RewardedAd. Try using RewardedAd. Refer to this documentation https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/rewarded